# Android how to prevent binding to Remote Messenger Service twice to prevent java.lang.IllegalStateException: This message is already in use

Tags: android, android-service-binding, react-native

While developing [react-native geolocation module](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) I run into following problem with binding to Remote Messenger Service.

I'm using [LocationService](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/LocationService.java), which is basically same as [MessengerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample) from android service example. [LocationService](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/LocationService.java) can live in separate process, so communication with it is via Messenger IPC. I'm binding to service in [BackgroundGeolocationModule](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/marianhello/react/BackgroundGeolocationModule.java#L397) in **doBindService** method:

```
void doBindService() {
    // Establish a connection with the service.  We use an explicit
    // class name because there is no reason to be able to let other
    // applications replace our component.
    if (mIsBound) { return; }

    mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

    final Activity currentActivity = this.getCurrentActivity();
    Intent locationServiceIntent = new Intent(currentActivity, LocationService.class);
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra("config", mConfig);
    currentActivity.bindService(locationServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_IMPORTANT);
}
```

Instance member **mIsBound** should prevent binding  to service twice. And it works pretty well in [similar module](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) I'm developing for cordova.

However react-native has feature that enables "live code reload" on changes in javascript part of application. Not sure how this "live reload" is implemented, but it doesn't call **onDestroy** (where unbind from service is done - code not in repo yet), but member **mIsBound** is false so it seems module is reinitialized completely while doing reload.

As result client is registered twice within single service instance, which result in following exception and app crash:

```
AndroidRuntime  D  Shutting down VM
                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                E  Process: com.marianhello.RNBGExample, PID: 11937
                E  Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack, fontPkg:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.resurrectio
                   nremix.pitchblack, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.resurrectionremix.pitchblack}
                E  java.lang.IllegalStateException: { when=0 what=4 target=com.marianhello.react.BackgroundGeolocationModule$IncomingHandler } This message is already in 
                   use.
                E      at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:538)
                E      at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
                E      at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
                E      at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
                E      at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:507)
                E      at android.os.Handler$MessengerImpl.send(Handler.java:721)
                E      at android.os.Messenger.send(Messenger.java:57)
                E      at com.marianhello.bgloc.LocationService.sendClientMessage(LocationService.java:369)
                E      at com.marianhello.bgloc.LocationService.handleLocation(LocationService.java:348)
                E      at com.marianhello.bgloc.AbstractLocationProvider.handleLocation(AbstractLocationProvider.java:81)
                E      at com.tenforwardconsulting.bgloc.DistanceFilterLocationProvider.onLocationChanged(DistanceFilterLocationProvider.java:318)
                E      at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:285)
                E      at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.-wrap0(LocationManager.java)
                E      at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:230)
                E      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                E      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                E      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                E      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                E      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                E      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 unknown:React  W  Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed.
```

My question **is there any way how to detect client is already bound to service**, so binding can be skipped in that case?

Related react-native issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9773

Comment: what does `sendClientMessage` & `handleLocation` methods look like?

Comment: https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/LocationService.java lines #378 and #325

Comment: so `mClients` > 1 and you are trying to send the same `Message` twice or more? yo should use `Message#obtain(Message orig)` then, BTW why not using "normal" `AIDL` instead of `Messenger`?

Comment: No message should never be send twice for same client and is obtained by Message#obtain. The problem is really that client is registered twice (I've manually debugged in android studio to confirm that) and it is only happening when app is reloaded from special react-native menu.

Comment: so just replace `ArrayList<Messenger> mClients` with `ArraySet<Messenger> mClients`: you will never have two same clients even if you call `bindService` twice and `MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT` the same client twice, again why `Messenger`? it is rather cumbersome compared to `AIDL`

Comment: this is actually great advice. will try and report results. thanks

Comment: I thought Messenger should actually be much simpler then AIDL. At least Android docs present it so: "This is the simplest way to perform interprocess communication (IPC), because the Messenger queues all requests into a single thread so that you don't have to design your service to be thread-safe."

Comment: Oh boy ArraySet was implemented only in API level 23. Not way to go.

Comment: so use `HashSet` or any other `java.util.Set<E>` you want

Comment: ok, so I can confirm that HashSet is not solution. I tooked screenshot of variables inside sendClientMessage before reload and after.

http://imgur.com/a/KwQaN

Comment: so you have two different clients, then send two different messages to them

Comment: From principle of module there is only one client (BackgroundGeolocationModule) that binds to a service. It is really only that it get registered (bounded) twice (Messenger hashCode is not same)

Comment: when are you sending MSG_UNREGISTER_CLIENT message?

Comment: that is actually the problem. Normally client is unregistered when plugin (it's activity) is destroyed (react-native onHostDestroy method). However when Reload is invoked, this method is not called, so client stay registered/bound. (this code is not yet in repo).

Comment: so you have two different instances of your client, thats why your flag (`mIsBound`) does not work, make it static and see what happens, otherwise if from some reason you gotta have two bound clients, simply call as i said before `Message#obtain(Message orig)` before sending the messages to your multiple clients

Comment: Making mIsBound static fixed the problem, but new appeared:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (com.marianhello.react.BackgroundGeolocationModule$IncomingHandler) {5dea424} sending message to a Handler on dead thread`
The exception makes sense though, as first instance of BackgroundGeolocationModule is dead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122821/discussion-between-mauron85-and-pskink).